# postgresql, concat json values if not null

Tags: postgresql

I'm using CONCAT with values from a jsonb columns.
sometimes one of those values could be `null` (json).

how can i COALESCE the whole returned field `xywh` to NULL ?

```
query := `SELECT
              CONCAT( 
                data->'x',',',
                data->'y',',', 
                data->'w',',', 
                data->'h') as xywh 
              FROM table`
```

Comment: `concat()` won't yield null if one parameter is null. But I think you need to use `->>` instead of `->`.

Comment: ok, but using `->>` returns `,,,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because [`concat`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-string.html) fucntion will ignore `NULL`

> Concatenate all arguments. NULL arguments are ignored.

if you want to let the result be `NULL` if any JSON field is null, we can try to use `||` concatenate string.

```
select  data->>'x' || ',' ||
        data->>'y' || ',' ||
        data->>'w' || ',' ||
        data->>'h'  
FROM table`
```